# queryset passes null in django

Tags: django

I am building my first ecom on django, i have a Item model with a category field on the DetailsView i would like to show relate items to the perticular item, for that i tried this.

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        related_items = Item.objects.filter(category=Item.category).order_by('category')
        context['related_items'] = related_items
        print(related_items)
        return context
```

but this does not works it prints:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

can someone please tell me what am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide which category you're looking for. For instance:

```
related_items = Item.objects.filter(category_id=1).order_by('category')
```

or

```
category = Category.objects.first()
related_items = Item.objects.filter(category=category).order_by('category')
```

So it has to be category type object or related to categories ids. One usual way for showing related items is like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        related_items = Item.objects.filter(category=self.get_object().category).order_by('category')
        context['related_items'] = related_items
        print(related_items)
        return contex
```

And if you want to exclude current item from your related items you can do something like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        item = self.get_object()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        related_items = Item.objects.filter(category=item.category).exclude(id=item.id).order_by('category')
        context['related_items'] = related_items
        print(related_items)
        return contex
```